# Regular expression for a date ranges

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, date-format

Is there a way to get dates from date string, like from "01-Apr-2013" to "01-Apr-2016" can you give any suggestions for writing Regex or JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

This is very specific to the input you are asking about, but it should work:

```
function parseInput(input) {
    var expr = /from \"(.*)\" to \"(.*)\"/g;
    var matches = expr.exec(input);
    if (input !== null) {
        var start = new Date(matches[1]);
        var end = new Date(matches[2]);
        if(start === null || end === null) {
            return null;
        }
        return {
            start: start,
            end: end
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Now you should get this:

```
parseInput('from "01-Apr-2013" to "01-Apr-2016"');
```

Object {start: Mon Apr 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), end: Fri Apr 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)}

Comment: I need rgex to serach date range in jquery data table(FYI https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html )  , i know other options  but i need through only rgex

Comment: my aim is to do ag-grid datatable (i.e https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/#gsc.tab=0) filters in jquery datatable

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regex, you can use this javascript code.

```
    var dateFrom = "01-Apr-2013";
    var dateLimit = "01-Apr-2016";
    var dateCheck = "04-Apr-2014"; //Suppose that this is the result of document.getElementById("userinput").innerHTML


    var d1 = formatDate(dateFrom).split("-");
    var d2 = formatDate(dateLimit).split("-");
    var c = formatDate(dateCheck).split("-");

    var from = new Date(d1[2], parseInt(d1[1]) - 1, d1[0]); 
    var to = new Date(d2[2], parseInt(d2[1]) - 1, d2[0]);
    var check = new Date(c[2], parseInt(c[1]) - 1, c[0]);


    (check > from && check < to) ? console.log("The user input is within the date range.") : console.log("Your date " + dateCheck + " is not between " + dateFrom + " and " + dateLimit + ".");


    function formatDate(date) {
        var monthNames = [
            "Jan", "Feb", "Mar",
            "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",
            "Aug", "Sep", "Oct",
            "Nov", "Dec"
        ];
        var month = date.substr(3, 3)
        var day = date.substr(0, 2);
        var monthIndex = date.indexOf(month) + 1;
        var year = date.substr(7, 4);

        return day + '-' + monthIndex + '-' + year;
    }
```

Comment: I need rgex to serach date range in jquery data table(FYI https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html )  , i know other options  but i need through only rgex